# Angular with angular-leaflet-directive not using mobile-friendly rendering

Tags: angularjs, mobile, angularjs-directive, leaflet

In the interest of learning how to use Angular, I thought I'd port a half-finished project of mine over from vanilla JavaScript.

- The original is here: http://john.bitsurge.net/bikeracks/
- The new version is here: http://john.bitsurge.net/bikeracks-angular
- angular-leaflet-directive: http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/

The first thing I noticed was that the angularized version was *significantly* more CPU heavy than the original. To see this, zoom way out and then zoom in again quickly. This is problem still manifests, even after removing all `$watch`s from the markers. `ng-stats` claims there are only 18 `$watch`s left, which is certainly acceptable.

The output from batarang suggests to me like things are actually pretty fast, but that contradicts that actual user experience, which is noticeably different between the two. Maybe these batarang times are per-call but there are just hundreds of calls being made?

## Batarang Output

[image: Batarang]

The second thing I noticed, while trying to debug the first, is that the angular version doesn't appear to be using any mobile-friendly styling! The buttons are hopelessly tiny and I can't read the attribution at all.

Any idea what's going on here?

## Angular looks like the desktop version

[image: angular-leaflet-directive has tiny controls]

## The vanilla app uses mobile-friendly sizes

[image: vanilla leaflet.js app]

Comment: Regarding the performance, use the profiling tools in Chrome, they are great once you poke through them for a bit.  You can capture CPU usage then do some actions that make it slow down then stop the capture and review what was happening all that time on the CPU (see which functions are taking the most time, what's calling them and reduce or eliminate it)

Comment: I did try out "batarang" to see what I could find. It appears that pretty much all of the time is being spent in `parentValueWatch` which is something internal to angular, presumably related to `$digest`ing? Edited my post to include some info about it.

Comment: Use the chrome profiling section to take CPU snapshots you get a lot more detail about what's being called use the flamechart to get a nice visual after you capture some data it makes figuring out what's going on much easier.  You can upload the saved CPU profile to dropbox or the like and link here then others can download and take a look too.

Comment: @shaunhusain After looking at it in the flame chart, it's really hard to blame anything. There are more calls to (program) in the angular version, but they are on the order of a few ms. Nothing serious. I'm probably more worried about the lack of mobile styling than anything. Performance or no, if that isn't resolvable then it's all in vain :(

Comment: Yah I hear yah just not sure what CSS or other changes are needed to make the leaflet directive mobile friendly.

Comment: @shaunhusain `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in the `<head>` did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I still have no good answer for the performance issues but the map rendering problems were due to a missing `<meta>` tag in the `<head>`.

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  ..
</head>
```

solves this one! \o/